# What is the network protocol of SqlConnection

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, networking, sqlconnection

When using .net SqlConnection to connect to the DB, what network protocol does it use to connect the application to the database? I tried googling it and reading the docs but couldn't find anything. Is it HTTP or something else?

Comment: You got the response in this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541281/what-is-the-default-network-protocol-in-sqlconnection-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The network protocol for SQL Server is the [Tabular Data Stream Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/b46a581a-39de-4745-b076-ec4dbb7d13ec) or TDS, and it runs over TCP/IP, Named Pipes, or (for local connections) Shared Memory.

Comment: Adding that all drivers, including SqlClient, use the [TDS protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/b46a581a-39de-4745-b076-ec4dbb7d13ec) to communicate with SQL Server over those transports.